# How to match two array and set the value in groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have two array below

```
 def array1 = ["descrip" , "treat" , "diagonis"]
 def array2 = ["123" , "345" , "678"]
```

Now I want to set my jcr content as below.

if body contains descrip then set it to 123 and if it contains treat then set to 345 and if it contains diagonis then set to 678

How can I achieve this in groovy script ?

Comment: What JCR content? What have you tried? What input do you have? What output do you expect? When you say "_set to 345_"... Set what to 345?

Comment: `[array1, array2].transpose().collectEntries()` will probably help but as @tim_yates says, you need to better define inputs and outputs for a more fleshed out answer.